# advanced filter search in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way (with a plugin or custom code) to create an advanced search like those links below?
I mean, the user should have the option to select some "tags" or "terms" or "category" and then all the posts containing those tags to be displayed.

Links:

1. http://www.olx.gr/cars-cat-378 (on the left sidebar)
2. http://www.car.gr/classifieds/trucks/search/

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to create a custom search page template that way you have full control over what is searched for, follow this page and you can extend it for tags, categories or any taxonomy you want to query http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Or, you could look at a number of plugins to take of it for you including this one http://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/

Answer (score 0):

I built a plugin that allows you to create advanced search forms using just a shortcode - http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/

I know its late but hope someone finds it useful ;)